# My PayPal gateway has a weird design on Android

Tags: android, paypal

I am using PayPal SDK on Android and when I run my Genymotion emulator, the display is not like it should be. The text has a grey background color. Images are better than words so here you are :

What I have :

[image]

What it should be :

[image]

I followed this tutorial : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paypal-integration-tutorial/

So I have two questions :

1) How do you I solve this?

2) While I'm at it, how can I customize the rendering of the PayPal app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I had a theme in my manifest file that had a dark background. I don't remember why I set that theme in the first place. But also, I don't understand how it affects the paypal app since it only concerns my application in the first place. Anyway, I replaced that theme with a standard one :

```
 <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

And now it works.